# atomic needed for readonly properties and scalars?

Tags: objective-c

I know there has been much discussion, one of which is https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969166/1724763 but the answer is not very clear.

I just want focus on specific use cases of atomic not found elsewhere (in the context of ARC)

For example, I have :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) someobject;
```

In this case, someobject is written once in `init` and readonly thereafter by multiple threads. 
Do I have to make it `atomic`? What exactly does the getter do? just return the pointer?

For scalars and non-objective c objects, can I just make them `nonatomic` for multi-thread readwrite? I understand that on Intel processors reading and writing an aligned int is always atomic.

Also, when accessing an atomic property, should I assign to a local variable first and use the local var to improve performance?

Comment: Search for discussions of atomic vs. nonatomic. atomic avoids crashes when a property is accessed by multiple threads, but doesn't make your code thread safe. As a result, atomic is very rarely used.

Comment: @gnasher729 Lucas asked this question in response to the atomic vs. nonatomic details.   It is a valid and specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nonatomic` is safe in this case (where *this case* is an object that is static throughout the app's session).

No need to do the `retain`/`autorelease` dance, even.

For all intents and purposes, this is equivalent in behavior to your typical `sharedInstance` method.   Specifically, the `readonly` value is computed in a thread safe, exclusionary, manner and, once computed, the value *never ever changes*.

As far as performance?  There is no reason to assign to a local variable until you identify a quantifiable and repeatable real world performance issue.