# Global Variables in Objective C++

Tags: ios, objective-c

All,

I have numerous arrays in the top of my .m file :

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property NSArray *allLogos;
@property NSArray *allcontent;
@property NSArray *allpostode;
@property NSArray *allname;
@property NSArray *alladdress;
@property NSArray *alladdress2;
@property NSArray *alllat;
@property NSArray *alllong;
@property NSArray *alllocationsID;
@property NSArray *alllocationsCity;
```

I need these as global arrays, so all the methods can see these. I have completely forgot how to make sure these NSArrays can be seen in all methods in the .m file. I need to do this because methods update these Arrays and then tableViews and PickerViews need to use them for .count etc. 
thanks

Comment: why not wrap them in a class? If you want only a single copy then use a Singleton.

Comment: i can wrap then in a class like class.h file I get that. I hear the Singleton word a lot but not exactly sure what it means

Comment: Singleton Class is a way of design. You have only one class and its instance. Each of your object have access to one instance which is shared. Try searching you will find many examples of singleton class in obj-c

Comment: Here have a look at my post, I explained it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906005/dynamic-global-variables-in-ios-app/21907111#21907111

Comment: as @AntonijoDev said, Singleton class is a best way to accomplish this

Comment: thanks guys, I am looking at the singleton class now, but still unsure I don't really need to run it with GCD.

Comment: @user3328028 Why does your title indicate `Objective-c++` when this is just `objective-c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access following arrays in all class then don't make property in .m class.declaration in .m if you want to make private.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property NSArray *allLogos;
@property NSArray *allcontent;
@property NSArray *allpostode;
@property NSArray *allname;
@property NSArray *alladdress;
@property NSArray *alladdress2;
@property NSArray *alllat;
@property NSArray *alllong;
@property NSArray *alllocationsID;
@property NSArray *alllocationsCity;
```

Comment: So if you want to make these global then don't put them as @property ? Is that what your saying ?

Comment: no no i am saying that if you have to access any variable in any other class then make its property, but set it into .h file instead of setting in .m class,if you set those in .m then they become private and other class can not access them. @user3328028

Answer (score 0):

Here you find how to create Singleton Class in Objective-C : [Objective-c singleton]:([What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like))

Comment: Check this link too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c