# Atomic property of a nonatomic primitive vs. nonatomic property of an atomic primitive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, atomic

One issue that I have have with a property like:

`@property (atomic, assign) NSInteger variable;`

Is that if I forget it's atomic, I may reference the ivar directly and undo that atomicity. However, if I declare this:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) _Atomic(NSInteger) variable;`

Then it's always atomic whether I'm using the getter/setter or accessing the ivar, correct? So should we prefer the latter? My single-threaded benchmarks indicate that these two have similar speed for the setter, although I don't know if that changes depending on what's going on concurrently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347236/which-is-threadsafe-atomic-or-non-atomic

Comment: Note that `_Atomic()` doesn't protect direct access from causing bugs.  Namely, direct access means you are bypassing KVO change notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a *definitive* answer to your question, but as no other answers exist at the time of writing I'll offer the following in the hope it helps.

Declared properties, along with the `nonatomic` qualifier (by default properties were atomic and `atomic` did not exist), were introduced in Objective-C 2.0 circa 2009. `_Atomic()` comes from C11, circa 2011.

So we have two independent language developments addressing atomicity.

Objective-C is not rigorously defined, the last "specification" of the whole languages dates from 2009 despite extensions since then, and I know of no specification that discusses how the atomic features of C and the atomic properties of Objective-C interact. So as with many Objective-C questions it is down to what the compilers do.

With the current Xcode 8.x compilers targeting Intel appear to produce code which respects atomicity, up to at least 128 bits (the limits of testing for this answer), for all combinations of `atomic` and `_Atomic()` – though specifying both is somewhat redundant. Code produced for `atomic` is *more likely* to involve spin locks and of course involve function calls; while `_Atomic()` is *more likely* to use cpu exchange instructions and be compiled inline.

> So should we prefer the latter? [`_Atomic()`]

If you intend to use direct access to the backing variable, and I'll skip any discussion of the merits or otherwise of doing that, then probably.

If you don't intend to access the backing variable directly then using `Atomic()` might exchange a spin lock call for a single cpu instruction, each with its own impacts, so any preference is down to how you weigh those.

In short: YMMV, the above applies to Intel, Xcode 8.x, etc. Hope it was some help, interesting question.